# Why can't a yogi visit mosque?

Tags: scripture, yogi, nath

Yesterday, CM of Uttar Pradesh, India said that as a 'Yogi' he will not goto mosque foundation laying program.

https://www.opindia.com/2020/08/yogi-adityanath-up-cm-ayodhya-mosque-ground-breaking-ceremony-attend/amp/

For those who don't know , Yogi Adityanath besides being Chief Minister of UP, is also head (chief priest) of Gorakhnath Math in Gorakhpur.

My question is whether there is anything in scriptures that prohibits him from visiting a mosque. If so , please share.

Comment: Good question :-) is a Yogi of Nath panth not allowed or any Yogi is not allowed?

Comment: @srimannarayana k v - Not sure which one he is alluding to. But any thing that validates or invalidates will be helpful. Ofcourse if someone can specifically answer from nath panth scriptures ( I think there is just one that might cover this area - Goraksha Samhita ) then that would be great

Comment: Is this a political statement or is it a spiritual statement?

Comment: @Pradip Gangopadhyay - When he says "as a yogi I won't go", I believe he is saying it from a religious / spiritual angle . Thus my question

Comment: @Carmensandiego: May be he was referring to [Manu smriti 4.79](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc200183.html)

Comment: Doubt it @srimannarayana k v

Comment: According to the general rules, a sanyasi should not stay at a place for [more than a few days at a place](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/23805/3869), except in special conditions.  Now a days,  it appears it's not being followed. May be the Nath panth sanyasis have different rules.

Comment: @srimannarayana k v , - By no stretch can the head of sampradaya be considered a sanyasi

Comment: @Carmensandiego: I don't want to comment on Nath Panth's traditions, as I have not read their literature.  I know that Sri Matsyendranath or Sri Gorakhnath was the originator of their tradition.

Comment: Hi, I would recommend [Reading this article](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/i-dont-discriminate-as-cm-but-as-hindu-wont-attend-mosque-event-yogi/articleshow/77404198.cms)

Comment: As mentioned in above article by @JenilDave, for a Hindu the general rule is to not associate or engage in the affairs of mleccha religions. I'm sure you will find a dozen rules prohibiting contact with mleccha cultures or religions. Unfortunately, because of 1000 years of mleccha rule, Hindus today are forced to coexist and be cordial, but strictly speaking, Yogi Adityanath is correct when he says "as a Hindu, he will not go to a mosque"

Comment: @RamAbloh - I don't see any mention of "general rule to not engage in affairs of mleccha religion" in the link posted by JenilDave. If you are aware of such rules , please post. However please ensure that rules are emphasis on mleccha religion (particularly their place of worship) and not mleccha people .

Comment: No, I didn't mean the article above says that. I mean there are general rules against going to mleccha territories and involving in mleccha customs in the dharmashastras. However, because they were written much before the advent of Islam into Indian lands, a mosque in today's India is a mleccha structure due to invasion and forceful occupation. So the modern-day situation as described in that article is equivalent to the ancient rules.

Comment: See, the point I'm trying to make is that in regards to foreign invader religions that came to India in medieval times, you will not find specific rules for them in ancient dharmashastras. But it does not mean we should not use intelligence and pragmatism to take inspiration from the ancient dharmashastras to re-apply the rules to new situations.

Comment: @Carmensandiego: Manu smriti says **One shall not associate with murderers of children, ungrateful men, murderers of a refugee, and murderers of women,—even though they may have been duly purified**.  I think this is applicable even to Sanyasis of Hinduism.

Comment: @Carmensandiego: One of the definitions of the word mlecchaa is barbarer.  So this rule may fit for your question

Comment: @srimannarayana k v - I will take a look at manusmriti . It might have more such pointers